# Regex Match decimal number between 0 to 1

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to match a decimal number between 0 and 1 (inclusive), but the regex I wrote will match anything more than 1 too: https://regex101.com/r/mN1iT5/3

How can I solve this

```
^[0-1]{1}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Comment: [`^(0?(\.\d+)?|1)$`](https://regex101.com/r/0Hcxpw/1)

Comment: I do not understand. Your above regex does not match with the regex from the demo. Your above regex should work fine.

Comment: `^(0\.[0-9]{1,2}|1\.00?)$` this does.

Answer (score 3):

Do:

```
^(?:0*(?:\.\d+)?|1(\.0*)?)$
```

- `0*(?:\.\d+)?` matches any number of `0` followed by one or digits
- `1(\.0*)?` matches `1` followed by a decimal point, and any number of `0`s
- The above two are `|` (OR-ed) to match any one of them

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN1iT5/240)